# Do two walk together unless they have agreed to do so? What is the significance of this rhetorical question?

Tags: amos

> Amos3:3 Do two walk together
> unless they have agreed to do so?
> 4Does a lion roar in the thicket
> when it has no prey?
> Does it growl in its den
> when it has caught nothing?
> 5Does a bird swoop down to a trap on the ground
> when no bait is there?
> Does a trap spring up from the ground
> if it has not caught anything?
> 6When a trumpet sounds in a city,
> do not the people tremble?
> When disaster comes to a city,
> has not the Lord caused it?

Do two walk together unless they have agreed to do so?

Does it carry Messianic significance?

Answer (score 2):

The prophecy of Amos 3:1-8 is as significant for the spiritual world as it is for the physical/natural world.  It is divided into three sections:

**1. Statement of Purpose - God will punish Israel because they sinned**

- **V1** Hear this word that the LORD has spoken against you, O children of Israel, against the whole family that I brought up out of the land of Egypt:
- **V2** “Only you have I known [chosen] from all the families of the earth; therefore I will punish you for all your iniquities.”

**2. Every effect has its cause**

- **V3** Can two walk together without agreeing where to go?
- **V4** Does a lion roar in the forest when he has no prey?
- Does a young lion growl in his den if he has caught nothing?
- **V5** Does a bird land in a snare where no bait has been set?
- Does a trap spring from the ground when it has nothing to catch?
- **V6** If a ram’s horn sounds in a city, do the people not tremble?
- If calamity comes to a city, has not the LORD caused it?

**3. Conclusion - Israel will be punished because they have sinned and so God is warning them**

- **V7** Surely the Lord GOD does nothing without revealing His plan to His servants the prophets.
- **V8** The lion has roared— who will not fear? The Lord GOD has spoken— who will not prophesy?

Thus, we have a quintessentially Hebrew way of saying that Israel has caused their own downfall by their sinfulness.  This results in a series of cause and effects statements:

- Israel's sinning >> will result in God's impending punishment
- God's impending punishment >> will result in God's warning messages
- God's warning messages >> will/should result in people trembling and (hopefully) reforming

Comment: Indeed an excellent answer +1